Problem with the package nomencl to produce glossaries
I have the following MWE:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\part{Problems}
Here, some text.
\nomenclature[A]{M}{conjugate transpose}

\part{Solutions}
Here, some text.
\nomenclature[A]{M}{conjugate transpose}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}

that when I run:
latex file
makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls
latex file

I get the error:
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thenomenclature}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \end{thenomenclature}

The problem seems to be related to some weird behaviour of makeindex. If we change the \part{Solutions} by a \pagebreak you get a file that works. The difference in between thw two *.nlo files produced are the pages numbers only. They are:
\nomenclatureentry{AM@[{M}]\begingroup conjugate transpose\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{2}
\nomenclatureentry{AM@[{M}]\begingroup conjugate transpose\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{3}

and
\nomenclatureentry{AM@[{M}]\begingroup conjugate transpose\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{2}
\nomenclatureentry{AM@[{M}]\begingroup conjugate transpose\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{4}

The first NLO file when processed by makeindex produces: \nompageref{2, 3} which is fine.
The second NLO file produces: \nompageref{2}, \nompageref{4} which the package nomencl is not able to deal with and produces the error.
The difference in processing by makeindex just based on different page-numbers seem to be pretty weird!
Any help with where the error is coming from would be appreciated.

You have asked this before, you should delete one of the questions. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723127/problem-with-code-to-input-a-file#comment1799130_723127

That has been deleted now that I have a much simpler MWE, which completely changed the nature of the probelm.

I don't think that the package expects and supports that you use the same \nomenclature command twice.

@UlrikeFischer This is not true! Just replace \part{Solutions} with a \pagebreak and you will see that it will index both entries and include both in the Glossary.

If you do that, you will see both (equal) entries are listed and both pages are listed.

it then doesn't break anymore. But that doesn't mean that the package expects such an usage. Sorry but the documentation writes "Issue the \nomenclature command (see Section 2.2) for each symbol
you want to have included in the nomenclature list. The best place
for this command is immediately after you introduce the symbol for
the first time." And their is only one first time for every symbol.  A nomenclature is a not an index where you expect that entries are listed more than once.

@UlrikeFischer You have a point! The documentation seem to imply that the listings should be unique. But I think the problem is with makeindex. In both cases (broken and unbroken, above) the *.nlo files produced are exactly the same, but with different pages (one lists page 2 and another page 4) -- that being the only difference.  The file with pages 2 and 3 get processed fine and produce: \nompageref{2, 3} which is correct. The file with pages 2 and 4 prodice: \nompageref{2}, \nompageref{4} which the package is not able to process on the second pass.

I have edited the question to highlight the weird processing of makeindex on files that differ only by a page-number.

sure. nomencl doesn't expect that you produce two entries which are then combined and contain two \nompageref. That is what I'm saying. Why are you trying to define the symbol twice? It doesn't make sense.

@UlrikeFischer  Yes! I understand your point -- but -- nomencl does process entries happening in two pages that are given in the right format. It is just a problem of makeindex that sometimes produce the file in the wrong format.
On the issue of double-indexation of the same symbol. It is not all that rare. There are many intances that the same symbol could be used in two different realms, like |  | for order of a group and for a ring and does need double-indexation, referring to separate locations in the manuscript.

makeindex does what the nomencl .ist file tells it to. the nomencl package then deals with the output.

no it is not makeindex. makeindex handles the entries nomencl provides and uses the style file nomencl provides and the result is processed by code from nomencl. And all this code from nomencl does not expect a second \nomenclature command for the same symbol. It works by luck if the pages build a continous range but will fail in all other cases.  I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with this code but you can not use nomencl for it.

As Karl Berry explained, in the tex-k mailing list, the problem is NOT with makeindex. Here it is just allowing two types of listing for the index, if the pages are consecutive or not. Pretty much what Ulrich Fischer explained above.
In the case of consecutive pages it outputs \nompageref{2, 3} that would allow the package, if the author desire, to do a listing of consecutive pages with an emdash, for example, like pages: 2--3.
In the case of pages far apart, only the comma in between applies and the listing does have to be: \nompageref{2}, \nompageref{4}, which could be rendered by nameref as pages: 2, 4. But nameref does NOT know how to handle that case, as exaplined by one of its author Boris Veytsman. The package was designed to handle only ONE definition for each symbol.
It is easy to see cenarios where the same symbol can be used for different things and could be listed in more than one page/location, and the package should be updated in the future to include that.
Meantime, you can easily go around this limitation of using this sequence for processing:
latex file.tex
makeindex file.nlo -s nomecl.ist -o file-broken.nls
sed 's/}, \\nompageref{/, /g' file-broken.nls > file.nls
latex file.tex

This takes advantage of of the fact that nomencl process the file well if it meets only one per line, and probably wil stop working as sson as the package is updated.

It works, very nice!
